# Как запустить локальную версию сайта?

Tags: сервер, домен

Добрый день. Есть сайт на хостинге, например, www.mysite.com, тот же сайт лежит на локальном сервере (Open Server) в папке "www.mysite.com". В итоге при вводе в браузер www.mysite.com естественно открывается версия сайта который лежит на хостинге. Как мне принудительно заставить Open Server открывать локальную версию сайта? Вариант менять локальное имя сайта мне не подходит, меня именно интересует вопрос возможно ли принудительно заставить Open Server открывать локальную версию сайта. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

OpenServer при запуске автоматически добавляет запись о локальном сайте в файл hosts

> \Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Вписав туда сайт с локальным ip браузер будет сразу обращаться именно на локальную версию, например

> 127.0.0.1 mysite.com

При обращении к mysite.com запрос сразу идет на локальную машину.

Может быть ситуация, когда OpenServer не смог добавить такую запись (прав не хватило например), тогда можно ее добавить самому.

Comment: Добавлю: антивирусы любят блокировать изменения этого файла. Возможно, придется отключить антивирус на время редактирования файла hosts

Answer (score 1):

Запустите OpenServer из под администратора, он автоматически изменит файл Hosts у вас на компьютере, после этого все обращения к сайту будут идти на www.mysite.com. Не забудьте проверить алиасы.

Comment: создаем папку в domain. для примера "test.com".
заходим в настройки openserver -> алиасы -> "исходный домен" www.test.com конечный домен "test.com"